# Rectangular Movement using ActionScript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript

Good evening. I am working on a simple project which involves a symbol moving in a rectangular fashion (Right, Up, Left, Down, Repeat) using an EVENT_FRAME handler. this is my code

```
import flash.events.Event;

var moveRate:Number = 20;
var maxX:Number = 500;
var minX:Number = 80;
var maxY:Number = 60;
var minY:Number = 320;
var endOfLineX:int = 0;
var endOfLineY:int = 0;

roboSym.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, move1);
roboSym.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, move2);

    function move1(e:Event):void
    {
    if (endOfLineX == 0)
    {
        roboSym.x +=  moveRate;
        if (roboSym.x >= maxX)
        {
                endOfLineX = 1;
        }
    }
    else if (endOfLineX == 1)
    {
        roboSym.x -=  moveRate;
        if (roboSym.x <= minX)
        {
            endOfLineX = 0;
        }
    }


    }
    function move2(e:Event):void
    {

    if (endOfLineY == 0)
    {
        roboSym.y -=  moveRate;
        if (roboSym.y <= maxY)
        {
            endOfLineY = 1;
        }
    }
    else if (endOfLineY == 1)
    {
        roboSym.y +=  moveRate;
        if (roboSym.y >= minY)
        {
            endOfLineY = 0;
        }
    }
    }
```

Thing is, the motion keeps going diagonal, and not in a straight motion. I know there is an error somewhere in my logic, but I can't pinpoint what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you've got 2 `EnterFrame` events, and they both have the variable endOfLine that makes them both go vertical and horizontal at the same time, which results in a diagonal motion. Also a small tip, you don't have to have 2 Event functions for EnterFame, you can just paste the code from move2 into move1 and it still works!
You basically got this:

```
function moveCombined(e:Event):void{
    if(endOfLineX == 1){
        roboSym.x += rate;
        //So the robot moves horizontal
    }else if(endOfLineX == 0){
        roboSym.x -= rate;
        //It still moves horizontal but the other way
    }
    //And you do the same for the vertical motion
    if(endOfLineY == 1){
        roboSym.y += rate;
        //So the robot moves vertical
    }else if(endOfLineY == 0){
        roboSym.y -= rate;
        //It still moves vertical but the other way
    }
}
```

So every frame, robotSym.x gets added (or subtracted) up with the rate, and also robotSym.y gets added (or subtracted) up with the rate. And that creates a diagonal motion.

Comment: I see! I finally got it now. I changed endOfLine into 1 variable only named endOfLine and made it have 4 states instead (0, 1, 2 and 3) which corresponds to right, up, left and down respectively (then repeat). Very helpful advice. Thank you sir Thomas!